# Pyspark-length of an element and how to use it later

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

So I have a dataset of words, I try to keep only those that are longer than 6 characters:

```
data=dataset.map(lambda word: word,len(word)).filter(len(word)>=6)
```

When:

```
print data.take(10)
```

it returns all of the words, including the first 3, which have length lower than 6. I dont actually want to print them, but to continue working on the data that have length greater than 6.

So when I will have the appropriate dataset, I would like to be able to select the data that I need, for example the ones that have length less than 15 and be able to make computations on them.

Or even to apply a function on the "word".

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something along this (untested):

```
data=dataset.map(lambda word: (word,len(word))).filter(lambda t : t[1] >=6)
```

In the `map`, you return a tuple of `(word, length of word)` and the `filter` will look at the length of word (the `l`) to take only the `(w,l)` whose `l` is greater or equal to 6

Comment: Try `(lambda w,l : l >=6)` or `(lambda t : t[1] >=6)` . Unfortunately, I dont have any environment to test it

Comment: TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
I also tried some different syntax , and I take one of these two errors

Comment: But how do I use again the element "word" of the dataset , when needed for later computations ?
I have to do the .map again at the dataset and apply the function in another .map with my function??
And I do that , every time I want to apply a function to the "word" ?

Comment: If you want to work on `word` again, you will need to use `map` again. Now, depending on what you have to do, maybe you can combine transformations ( `map`). I would suggest you to post another question with more context about what you try to acheive